# How to create a daily 'check-in' on a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newcomer to Ruby, and I'm trying to make a Rails app for class. Trouble is, being new to this all, I've hit an impasse and I don't know the best way to achieve my goals.

My app is this:

- A habit-building app where you set a daily goal, and set a bet with a friend that you will achieve this goal each day for 30days.
- Then you 'check-in' each day to confirm that you've practiced that habit in that calendar day.
- If you don't check-in, you fail the challenge and your friend wins the bet.

Thus far I've set up my models and have authentication with Devise.

How best would you recommend I go about setting up the 'check-in'?

Any and all suggestions and help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use devise `Trackable` module for satisfied your needs.

It will track with below column

> sign_in_count - Increased every time a sign in is made (by form,
> openid, oauth)
>
> current_sign_in_at - A timestamp updated when the user signs in
>
> last_sign_in_at - Holds the timestamp of the previous sign in
>
> current_sign_in_ip - The remote ip updated when the user sign in
>
> last_sign_in_ip - Holds the remote ip of the previous sign in

You can make your logic depends on this fields.

Fore more information visit :
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable

Comment: Hi Hardik, thanks for the input. Trackable is definitely an option, but the downside of that is that it will log a sign as the 'check-in', which isn't desirable if people are logging in to check comments etc, but haven't actually achieved their goal for the day.

Comment: Yes, for that you need to create business logic or you can set crone job to run everyday and check task is performed or not. please refere "whenever gem".